# Alpine JS model follows "Input must have uuid"

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I have a general AlpineJS situation in my Laravel project.
Just a wire:model and a updateListener in the PHP.

Since i input someting to the input-Field I'll get the following error (it´s counting up every second).

It´s the first time I have such an issue and the error message should be from AlpineJS cause I hadn´t defined something like that.
The error occours even when i have an empty update-function block.
When the wire:model is removed - no error occours.

```
<input wire:model="handleChange" type="text">

public function updatedHandleChange($value): void
{
// code
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at wire:key , all elements really should have unique ID, not sure if this is the same issue tho..

Comment: I tried that also but same issue occured.